# Upload files and show them under related list of Sobject

Tags: apex, visualforce

We have a requirement where we need to attach multiple files and store them under Files (related list) for particular Sobject.

I am able to insert the file but i am not getting the preview option neither when i am downloading the file is visible. Please help me out..

Adding debug log for reference.
CODE:

```
 Public String fileObj {get;set;}
    Public String contentLocation {get;set;}
    Public String fileName {get;set;}
     Public void UploadDocuments(){
            String filesUploadedList;
            String name = 'deepak';
            system.debug('\''+'/'+name+ '\'');
            system.debug('HIHI');
            String oppId;  
            fileObj  = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('fileObject');
            contentLocation = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('contentLocation');
            fileName = apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('fileName');
            system.debug('fileObj '+fileObj);
            system.debug('contentLocation '+contentLocation);
            system.debug('fileName '+fileName);
            //system.debug('fileObj '+JSON.stringify(fileObj));
            //oppId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');    
            oppId = '0069D000001rkq6QAA';
            ContentVersion Cv = new ContentVersion(ContentLocation = contentLocation,
                                                   VersionData = Blob.valueof(fileObj),PathOnClient = fileName,Title = fileName);

            insert Cv;

            ContentDocumentLink Cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
            list<ContentVersion> contentVersionList = [SELECT id,ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :Cv.id];
            List<ContentDocumentLink> toBeInsertedContentDocumentList = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
            system.debug('contentVersionList '+contentVersionList);
            for(integer i=0;i<contentVersionList.size();i++){
                Cdl.ContentDocumentId = contentVersionList[i].ContentDocumentId;
                Cdl.LinkedEntityId = oppId;
                Cdl.ShareType = 'V';
                Cdl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
                toBeInsertedContentDocumentList.add(Cdl);
            }

            insert toBeInsertedContentDocumentList;



            //return null;

        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change your share type of ContentDocumentLink  from "V" to "I". You can refer this document for additional help
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm

Make this below change in your code

```
Cdl.ShareType = 'V';
```

to

```
Cdl.ShareType = 'I';
```

Comment: I tried but that didnot help

Comment: Hi Deepak, Did you try uploading files with other file format, like PDF, if yes, then does it work  ? Is it visible in the files related list ? And finally, does the user have the right permissions to the related record ? Here is the link mentioning the supported formats for content files https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213786&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: The issue is resolved i had to change the conversion of file here 
VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(fileObj) instead of
 VersionData = Blob.valueof(fileObj)

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code in class to below line:-

```
VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(fileObj)
```

Instead of

```
VersionData = Blob.valueof(fileObj)
```

Which helped me to preview and even download the file.